# Why are next episode previews suddenly moved from TV to online?

Tags: anime-production, kill-la-kill

At the end of the 19th episode of *Kill la Kill*, it is announced that further episode previews will be moved to online.

> Hello, everyone! I have sad news for you today! This will be the final preview for the television broadcast of this show! From now on, please tune in to the web previews!

It appears that the main part's duration isn't increased all that much for the 20th episode, so the only reason I think this has is to attract viewers to the official website of the anime and, possibly, hook them on some other anime from the same TV channel or production studio.

Why did this happen?

Comment: Production sometimes do this with tight deadlines. Sometimes not enough of the next episode is finished (not enough ppl to finih the labor) and this gives them a bit more time to polish things up.

Comment: If it's just moved from TV to a website, it's still going to be animated, so…

Comment: Maybe to add more running time for the actual series. They only have so many minutes.

Comment: @noko if only it was for that. Instead the message about moving preview to online took about the same time as the actual preview usually does.

Comment: @user1306322 Not for that one episode but for the later ones.

Comment: @noko previews resumed in the later episodes!

Comment: So whoever was meant to make the preview for that one was late on that deadline.  They then put it online when it was completed...done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To promote the incoming anime.**

Apparently, [Animeism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animeism) (a late-night Japanese anime programming block on [MBS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mainichi_Broadcasting_System)) -- and to the extent of anime produced by MBS -- has a routine of cutting entirely/shortening next episode's previews by 15 seconds to promote incoming anime when it's nearing the end.

In this case, since *Kill la Kill*'s next episode's previews were 15 seconds long, they were entirely cut and replaced by PVs for *Riddle Story of the Devil* since episode 19 out of 24 (refer to the [Wikipedia's list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animeism#Titles) on block B2). Also, since they had worked on next episode's previews, they would be wasted if they hadn't shown them somewhere (e.g. official site).

Another example is *Hozuki's Coolheadedness* which had 30-seconds next episode's previews. In that case, they're shortened to 15 seconds then continue with *Knights of Sidonia*'s 15-seconds PV.

Lastly, even for non-Animeism anime, but produced by MBS like *Magi*, it's also affected. Their 15-seconds next episode's previews got entirely cut to show 15-seconds PV for *Haikyu!!*

---

> [previews resumed in the later episodes!](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/8785/why-suddenly-move-next-episode-previews-to-online-from-tv#comment11885_8785)

This is just a theory since I don't have enough information to make a conclusion, but if it's not simulcasted or otherwise on streaming sites which had more flexibility in time arrangement, then the next preview could be added manually from the official site.

---

Source:

- [matome blog (Japanese)](http://ponpokonwes.blog.jp/archives/3688279.html)
- Yahoo! Chiebukuro (Japanese): [1](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q12121826837), [2](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q12121405837)